# Inexplicable behaviour in MS Access full outer join?

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, outer-join

I attempt to do a full outer join of two tables `CMVSC` and `TOXOSC` in MS Access in order to examine which IDs are contained in both/just one of the tables:

```
(SELECT * FROM CMVSC LEFT JOIN TOXOSC ON CMVSC.ID = TOXOSC.ID)
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM TOXOSC LEFT JOIN CMVSC ON TOXOSC.ID = CMVSC.ID);
```

The query can be executed, but does not yield what I expected.

The first few records (sorted by ascending ID) in CMVSC are:

```
ID      CMV_NEGDATE CMV_POSDATE
10245   04.02.2010  28.06.1999
10642   08.10.1998  05.09.1991
```

The first few records (sorted by ascending ID) in TOXOSC are:

```
ID      TOXO_NEGDATE TOXO_POSDATE
10120   22.11.1993   05.04.1991
10261   09.02.1998   23.02.1996
```

And here are the first two records from the above query:

```
CMVSC.ID CMV_NEGDATE CMV_POSDATE TOXOSC.ID TOXO_NEGDATE TOXO_POSDATE
10120    22.11.1993  05.04.1991         
10245    04.02.2010  28.06.1999
```

Note how the record from `TOXOSC` got assigned to the `CMV*` variables, just as the record from `CMVSC`.

**How is this possible?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that first subquery has first the `CMVSC` table and then the `TOXOSC` one. The second subquery has them in opposite order. The `UNION` takes the columns as they come and uses as columns titles the titles from the first subquery (therefore the mixing). Try this:

```
( SELECT CMVSC.*, TOXOSC.* FROM CMVSC LEFT JOIN TOXOSC ON CMVSC.ID = TOXOSC.ID)
UNION 
( SELECT CMVSC.*, TOXOSC.* FROM TOXOSC LEFT JOIN CMVSC ON TOXOSC.ID = CMVSC.ID);
```

---

Another way would be to use both `LEFT` and `RIGHT` join:

```
(SELECT * FROM CMVSC LEFT JOIN TOXOSC ON CMVSC.ID = TOXOSC.ID)
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM CMVSC RIGHT JOIN TOXOSC ON TOXOSC.ID = CMVSC.ID);
```

Comment: I did not expect the `UNION` to ignore the column identifiers. Is this standard SQL92 behavior or an access botch?

Comment: This is standard. `UNION` does not use the column identifiers but the order of the column list (and any titles besides the first subquery one's are ignored).

Comment: @Simon Stelling: SQL-92 provides [`UNION CORRESPONDING`](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=406_pJtiJ6sC&pg=PA119&dq=%22SQL+and+Relational+Theory%22+%22How+to+Write+Accurate+SQL+Code%22+%22union+corresponding%22&hl=en&ei=IvZUTuDrHMjAtAa0oKn2Dw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) for the behaviour your were expecting. Needless to say, the Access team have yet to implement it :(

Comment: @onedaywhen: Thnx for the info. I hadn't heard of it (or heard and forgotten it ...). Are there RDBMS that support it?